# Problema para buscar cantidad de valores en un rango de fecha

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos días/tarde/noche Hagamos de cuenta que tengo la siguiente tabla, llamada T1:

| ID | Vivienda | Evento | Creado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 958 | Dpto | DONE | 2022-01-01 |
| 1024 | Casa | DONE | 2022-03-01 |
| 325 | Ph | DONE | 2022-03-05 |
| 014 | Casa | WAITING | 2022-04-05 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc |

Luego tengo otra tabla, llamada T2

| ID_S | Estado |
| --- | --- |
| 958 | Activo |

Lo que busco es encontrar todos los usuarios, que tengan mas de 3 veces el Evento 'Done' en los últimos, por ejemplo, 3 meses y que tengan el estado 'Activo' (ID=ID_S), sesgado por lo que tienen "Casa"

Entonces se me ocurre lo siguiente

```
select ID, count(*) from T1 group by ID having count (*)>3
and ID in (select ID_S from T2 where Estado='Activo')
and ID in (select ID from T1 where Vivienda='Casa' 
           and Creado::date between '2022-03-01' and current_date())
```

El problema con esto, es que si, me trae todos los usuarios que tuvieron mas de 3 veces el Evento "Done".... pero históricamente, no 3 veces en un rango de tiempo (era medio obvio...). Se me ocurrieron algunas otras cosas, como intentar meter en el primer select la limitaciòn de fecha pero todo lo que intenté me tira error (T1.Creado is not a valid group by expression; in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause; entre otras que bueno, fui intentando y aprendiendo el por qué no lo puedo hacer jaja) .

-Estoy usando snowflake

-La columna 'Creado' es timestamp (en realidad es 2022-01-01 16:55:01.299, puse solo aaaa/mm/dd para más comodidad)

Cualquier ayuda/consejo se aprecia, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, no eh usado snowflake, pero por lo que veo la sintaxis es un poco parecida a la de sql server, te mando un ejemplo basado en SQL server, espero este ejemplo te sirva:

```
select ID 
from
(
   select T1.* 
    from T1 
    inner join T2 on T1.ID=T2.ID_S
    where T2.Estado='Activo'
    and T1.Creado>='2022-03-01'
    and T1.Creado<=getdate()
) a
group by ID 
having (count (ID)>3)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto! Si no te molesta tengo una consulta: having (count (ID)>3) me da lo mismo que poner having count (*)>3  (eso mismo pero sin el ID). La lógica detrás tal vez en SQL sea diferente-->en tu caso le estas especificando que cuente solo "ID"? Ya que si no lo especificas te tiraría error?

Comment: Buen día, es correcto, ambas formas funcionan correctamente ya sea "having count (*)>3" o "having (count (ID)>3)", te traerá el mismo resultado, yo lo puse de esa forma para que el código sea un poco más claro y "limpio".

Comment: Perfecto, mil gracias! Una última cosa: veo que sabés mucho de esto, tené algún libro/canal de youtube/curso/etc que recomiendes?

Comment: Pues en la página de microsoft hay muy buena documentación, pero igual [en esta pagina](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-training/) hay muy buena información y a mi parecer esta muy bien explicado. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

mira, te dejo un ejemplo de código que un compañero compartió, el básicamente lista las veces que aparecen sucesiones de datos, échale un ojito:

[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f9f74f6f7e8d81e16bb06aefd2f54d0d)